# Excel macro non VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that opens up with a Macro tab with a code that doesn't seem to be VBA. When enabling the macros warning in excel it formats the file as per the macro.

What type of code is this? Does anyone know where I can get more information how how to code this type of macros?

See below what this the code for this macro looks like:

[image: ExcelNonVBAMacro]

Comment: That is deffinitelly not a macro. They seem to be reference formulas for a macro, have you found any code in the Visual Basic editor? try opening it with alt+f11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an old Excel 4 macro, from before there was a VBA editor.  It is still supported in the latest excel versions - right-click on the "sheet tabs" in an excel workbook, hit "insert", and one of the options in the dialog is to insert an `MS Excel 4.0 Macro`.  Select that, and it will insert a sheet that looks like a worksheet, but allows macros like this.

Some useful links on migrating them:

[Working with Excel 4.0 Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Working-with-Excel-4-0-macros-ba8924d4-e157-4bb2-8d76-2c07ff02e0b8)

And:

[Migrating Excel 4 Macros to VBA](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2010/02/16/migrating-excel-4-macros-to-vba/)

If you want to try to work with the Excel 4 macro, you can get a help file (from Microsoft) [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1465).

Answer (score 2):

Wow. This takes me back. It's the pre-1997 way of coding macros, before Microsoft Excel 1997<sup>1</sup>.

Lotus 1-2-3 pioneered it. Are you sure the workbook didn't begin life as a 1-2-3 spreadsheet?

Naturally you ought to attempt to port such stuff to newer technologies despite Excel still supporting in-worksheet macros.

There are a few conversion tools dotted around the internet. See http://www.xlhelp.com/Excel/Lotus.htm for example.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which, in my humble opinion, was at the time the best application ever written.

Comment: That threw me.. it just looked like a normal sheet calling UDF's.. but you are absolutely right.. I had forgot about the old lotus format :). Good shout!

Comment: The files are produced by Oracle BI Discoverer 11g. Hopefully the new versions of Oracle will be a bit more updated with the macros

Comment: @Selrac: Indeed. And note the other answer (that I've upvoted) is more truthful than this one, even after my cheeky edit.